# Apply a spatial input condition in QField

Tags: qfield

In a QField project, I have two layers:

1. MEASUREMENT POINT
2. PARCEL

When an agent wishes to record a point on a parcel in the field, if the agent's geographical position does not correspond to the location of the parcel where he is, the entry will not be executed.

Comment: Are they always using "Cursor locked at position" to create the points? (They dont place the point manually by "clicking")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, QGIS does not treat geometry like any other attribute of a feature class - it should, but it doesn't.

A possible workaround is to create a field, e.g. a uuid field. Do not use the UUID generator widget type, use a text edit. Make the widget uneditable. Set constraints of the field to NOT NULL and 'enforce constraint'.

Under default value use overlay_intersects() expression or similar to check the current point feature is within your target polygon. Be aware that depending on how you use overlay_intersects() it may return a boolean or an array. (Check out the syntax and options for overlay_intersects() in the manual).  Assuming your point can be within any polygon of your target layer, you can simply use overlay_intersects('myTargetLayer'), which returns a boolean: true if it is inside a polygon, false if not. You can then put this in a case statement something like

```
case
     when overlay_intersects('myTargetLayer') then uuid()
     else null
end
```

If the expression returns null, then you will not be able to save the feature.

EDIT:
Screenshots of it working. In this case I am using tree_pt as my point layer and tgtnote_ar as my polygon layer. For 'tree_pt' I have a text field with default set to

```
case
     when overlay_intersects('tgtnote_ar') then uuid
     else null
end
```

(Note: the 'when' clause, could be written as *when overlay_intersects('tgtnote_ar') = True then uuid*, but the '= True' is implicit.)

I have constraints set to 'Not null' and 'Enforce not null constraint' checked.

[image]

Here is a short GIF of it working. First two attempts at plotting a point are outside of a polygon: the feature form opens but can't be saved. Third attempt is inside a polygon. The feature form opens and the save button is enabled - I save the feature.

[image]

Comment: Hello ,@Oisine your method seems to answer my problem. When I enter the expression: overlay_intersect ('TagetLayer'), it returns TRUE or FALSE. I'd like it to be impossible to type when the expression returns False.

Comment: Add '=False' no quotes after overlay_intersects('TagetLayer').

Comment: Hi @Oisin, Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, the expression: overlay_intersects('TagetLayer', false), still doesn't make it possible to disable input when the false condition is checked.

Comment: It worked for me. The feature form opens but cannot be saved, so user must cancel.

Comment: what is your full expression please? Did you use only overlay_intersects('TagetLayer', false) or did you add the declaration with CASE?

Comment: The full expression is as stated in the answer, with a case statement. The case statement is important. Also, you say you want to accept input when overlay_intersects() is false, but that is when the point is not within a polygon - not what you asked for in your question.  If you do want to accept input when the point is not inside of a polygon, the syntax is overlay_intersects('myTargetLayer')=False, NOT overlay_intersects('myTargetLayer', False). ALso, remember to set the  constraints of the uuid field to NOT NULL and 'enforce constraint'.

Comment: Indeed, I don't want to accept any input when outside the polygon. So if the value of the field returns to false, input must be impossible. Here's my case expression:  case 
when overlay_intersects( 'ParcelleCloterre')  then true
else false
end

Comment: If you don't want to accept input when point outside, then you want overlay_intersects() to be TRUE, i.e. point inside polygon. Expression should be as stated in my answer above, the whole case statement. This is the default expression for your uuid field, which should have constraint 'not null' enforced. It works, I have tested it several times.

Comment: I've edited my answer with more detail.

Comment: Hello @Oisin. Thanks again for your help. Your method works very well.  I found where my mistake is. Indeed, one of the objectives of my project is to hide the form when adding an element. With this constraint, the expression doesn't work. When I use the option to display the form when adding an element, it works fine.

Comment: Hi @Donovan93. If you found the answer useful, i'd be grateful if oyu could accept it as an answer.

Comment: Merci @Oisin, je viens de valider. Merci pour votre aide.